# How to find what chrome extension is doing automated abuse of google searching searches? When googling im getting warning that some extension abusing

Tags: google-chrome

When googling im getting warning that some extension is abusing google.
How to find what chrome extension is doing automated abuse of google searching searches?

[image: Google warning]

Comment: It could be an extension that tries to create a VPN connection

Comment: @Robbi i checked what is VPN- no, i dont have such extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Google message may also be misleading.
I suggested that control because I also frequently receive that message when I create a VPN connection with a stand-alone program (no extension).
If this message appears **without any VPN connections** then you could:

1. Disable each extension and check if the problem persists
   (you could open chrome with this option:
   --disable-extensions )
2. Enable extensions individually one by one verifying then if the problem persists
3. Try another browser (i.e Firefox)
4. Launch an antivirus deep scan

Maybe these things are obvious but I can't suggest you alternatives